# Playwright extraHTTPHeaders authentication is throwing 403 for API testing

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

**Postman works:**

In Postman, I use the below to generate the `accessToken`. It works fine and I am able to run the subsequent requests.

```
{
    "userLoginData": {
        "email": "abc@abc.com",
        "password": "abc"
    }
}
```

**Playwright, not working:**

When I do a `https://www.base64encode.org/` for the above email:password which is `abc@abc.com:abc` I get an encoded value. I use that in my `playwright.config.ts` file as

```
extraHTTPHeaders: {
    "Authorization":"Basic SGHSDFGsfasdfasdf"
  },
```

However, this isn't working when I run a test with a get (or any other) request. I am getting an error.

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality


Expected: 201
Received: 403
```

Here's my `spec` code

```
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("API Login", async ({ request, baseURL }) => {
  const endPoint = `${baseURL}/users/all`;

  const all_users = await request.get(endPoint, {
  });
  expect (all_users.status()).toBe(201);
  expect (all_users.ok()).toBeTruthy();
  console.log(all_users);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

base64 code is difference.

```
const btoa = (str: string) => Buffer.from(str).toString('base64');
const credentialsBase64 = btoa(`abc@abc.com:abc`);
console.log(credentialsBase64) // YWJjQGFiYy5jb206YWJj
```